# Excel Office.js - chart.getImage() on Mac issue

Tags: excel, office-js

I use [chartObject.getImage()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/chart) to get images of Excel charts so they can be displayed in Word and PowerPoint.  I have been doing this for months and it works great on Office for Windows.  I recently discovered (via customer complaints) that there are issues when getImage is done on Excel for Mac. See below for typical example (I added black border).

[image: Shows offset issue on Mac]

getImage() in Excel for Mac always seems to offset the chart image.  Often the chart is not visible at all (image is all white).

I've tried changing the height, width, and fittingMode (Fit, FitAndCenter, Fill) parameters and nothing seems to fix the issue.

You can also see the issue using our [Store add-in](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104380955).

Is this a known issue?  Is there a way to resolve it?

**To duplicate:**

In Script Lab, on Sheet1, add any "Chart 1".

The further the chart is from the top-left of the sheet, the more offset the image is.  So, if you put the image around f20, then you'll only see the bottom-right corner of the chart.

```
$("#run").click(run);
function run(){
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var chart = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").charts.getItem("Chart 1");
    var image = chart.getImage();
    return ctx.sync().then(function () {        
        var srcImage = "data:image/png;base64, " + image.value;
        $("#chart").attr("src", srcImage);
    });
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
}



<p class="ms-font-m">Shows the chart image below</p>
<button id="run" class="ms-Button">
    <span class="ms-Button-label">Run code</span>
</button><br/>
<img id="chart" src="" alt="" />
```

Comment: The product team uses the [OfficeDev/office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js) GitHub repository to track/manage issues related to the Office.js APIs. I'd suggest that you report this problem by [logging an issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) there, and include a link to this Stack Overflow post, so that this post can be updated when the issue is resolved. Also, if you can include some code that reproduces the issue that you've described, that would likely expedite the troubleshooting process.

Comment: I added it here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/55. I also added repro steps and code.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue via the GitHub repo. Per the product team's recent comment there, it sounds like this issue will be fixed in the 16.10 February release of Mac Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in Mac Excel version 16.10